# Excel VBA Retrieve Constant from Worksheet Code Fails When New Code is Written

Tags: vba, excel, macros

In an attempt to retrieve constants from each worksheet in some reporting workbooks I use, three years ago I wrote some code that gets included in each worksheet.  Here's an example of the code:

```
    Option Explicit
    ' Determine the type of worksheet
    Private Const shtType As String = "CR"

    Public Function GetShtType()
        GetShtType = shtType
    End Function
```

In other code that gets the values from the worksheets for processing, the following section of code is used, where 'wksToCheck' is the worksheet in question.  This code is stored in a personal macro workbook, not in the workbook with the worksheet code:

```
    ' Get the sheet 'type' if it has one
    On Error Resume Next
    shtType = wksToCheck.GetShtType()
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' We do not have a type
        shtType = "Unknown"
        Err.Clear
    End If ' Err.Number...
    On Error GoTo Error_BuildTemplateWbk
```

My problem is, I use the code above to process workbooks several times a week, and I have for the past three years.  Now, I am trying to write some new code with the above block to process the report workbooks in a different way.  However, when I run code with the above block now, I get a 'Method or Data Member Not Found' error on the '.GetShtType()' portion of the code.  I cannot compile the code and of course, consequently, the code doesn't work.  I have tried adding the worksheet code to a worksheet in the macro workbook to see if that would fix the problem.  It hasn't.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I am running Excel 2013 on a Windows 7 PC.  Any ideas?

Brian

Comment: So exactly what is different between the two scenarios - the one which works and the one which doesn't? Are you declaring your worksheet variables in a different way?  It's not clear from your question what caused it to stop working.  Likely related to the fact that a generic `Worksheet` object (ie. as far as it goes "out of the box") does not have a  `GetShtType` property: the compiler doesn't know you want to assign that to your "extended" worksheet object (which *does* have that property) hence the complaint.

Comment: Think of a plain Worksheet object as an instance of the `Worksheet` class: it has certain pre-defined methods etc, which Excel knows are associated with that type of object.  When you "extend" your worksheets to add custom properties/methods, the compiler doesn't know to expect that additional items and the compiler flags them up.

Comment: Yeah, looks to me like the top code snippet was part of a custom class with the `GetShtType` function as part of it.

Comment: `Dim wksToCheck As Object` will probably avoid the compile error, at the expense of losing the intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using late-binding, should avoid the error, `Dim wksToCheck As Object`, but you'll lose the intellisense.

If you're open to alternatives, you may have better luck simply using the `CallByName` function, or using worksheet's `CustomProperties`.

Using `CallByName` preserves backwards compatibility with your older workbooks if needed:

```
shtType = CallByName(wksToCheck, "GetShtType", VbMethod)
```

Or, using `CustomProperties` instead of a custom method, in your worksheets:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Const PropName$ = "ShtType"
Const ShtType$ = "CR"
On Error Resume Next
Me.CustomProperties(PropName) = ShtType$
If Err.Number = 13 Then
    Me.CustomProperties.Add "PropName", ShtType
End If
End Sub
```

Then,

```
' Get the sheet 'type' if it has one
On Error Resume Next
shtType = wksToCheck.CustomProperties("ShtType")
If Err.Number = 13 Then
    ' We do not have a type
    shtType = "Unknown"
    Err.Clear
End If ' Err.Number...
On Error GoTo Error_BuildTemplateWbk
```

Comment: You can also still declare `As Worksheet` if you're OK with using `CallByName` for the custom property.

Comment: Wow!  I can't believe the number of comments and an answer in such a short period!!  Thanks everyone for your comments and possible answer!  I'm going to try these things out and post which works best for me.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: I have used the CallByName and it seems to be working great!  It is also backwards-compatible with my old workbooks.  I have marked that as the answer and thanks so much for posting!